# Installing Ubuntu 13.10, ps2 keyboard not recognized (worked in 12.04)

Tags: keyboard, system-installation

I have a old laptop with a internal ps2 keyboard (right now it is running ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

I want to install the new version 13.10 but I found that the keyboard is not recognized. Can anyone help me? how can I put it working? I need to change the kernel version?

Well I think that was a bad choise withdraw some of the old support features.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how can you have an internal ps2 keyboard on a laptop? I thought it just had builtin keyboards...

Comment: @DanJohansen - pretty much the same interface, but is a likely to be a different internal connector - for example, most laptop integrated work via a USB interface, so do some wireless cards, fingerprint readers, etc - and you likely don't have USB ports dotted around the inside of your laptop. **user247507** - what model of laptop is this?

Comment: Its a LG-R400 model. I think that the kernel do not allow this kind  of keyboards (or maybe something in bios), if I connect an external USB keyboard it works right.